# Android : Gallery

Tags: android

I am working on app for editing photos.

I have a button in first activity and ImageView in second activity. When I click the button it would open gallery and I would be able to select an image. The selected image needs to appear in my ImageView in second activity but it doesn't. For time being i am displaying image in first activity it self but can anyone suggest me how to display that image in next activity.

Below is my code.

```
public class Camera_Gallery_Option extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private String selectedImagePath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_gallery_option);
        Button galleryButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        galleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                    SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                imageview.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the **selectedImageUri** to the second activity and set the uri to image view in the second activity ?

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class).setData(selectedImageUri));
```

In the SecondActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    imageView.setImageURI(getIntent().getData());
}
```